# Load video from iPhone library, modify frame and play it in real-time

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, avfoundation, core-video

I'm looking for a tips to develop an application for iPhone/iPad that will be able to process video (let's consider only local files stored on the device for simplicity) and play it in real-time. For example you can choose any movie and choose "Old movie" filter and want it like on old lamp TV.

In order to make this idea real i need to implement two key features:

1) Grab frames and audio stream from a movie file and get access to separate frames (I'm interested in raw pixel buffer in BGRA or at least YUV color space).

2) Display processed frames somehow. I know it's possible to render processed frame to OpenGL texture, but i would like to have more powerful component with playback controls. Is there any class of media player that supports playing custom image and audio buffers?

The processing function is done and it's fast (less than duration on one frame).

I'm not asking for ready solution, but any tips are welcome!

**Answer**

***Frame grabbing***.
It seems the only way to grab video and audio frames is to use AVAssetReader class. Although it's not recommended to use for real-time grabbing it does the job. In my tests on iPad2 grabbing single frame needs about 7-8 ms. Seeking across the video is a tricky. Maybe someone can point to more efficient solution?

**Video playback**. I've done this with custom view and GLES to render a rectangle texture with a video frame inside of it. As far as i know it's the fastest way to draw bitmaps.

**Problems**

- Need to manually play a sound samples
- AVAssetReader grabbing should be synchronized with a movie frame rate. Otherwise movie will go too fast or too slow.
- AVAssetReader allows only continuous frame access. You can't seek forward and backward. Only proposed solution is to delete old reader and create a new with trimmed time range.

Answer (score 3):

[This is how you would load a video from the camera roll..](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Accessing_the_iPhone_Camera_and_Photo_Library_%28Xcode_4%29)

[This is a way to start processing video. Brad Larson did a great job..](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

[How to grab video frames..](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for these tips.I saw them already and i'm familiar with them as author of OpenCV Tutorial for iOS. But you make me sure there is no another option to my problem except the AVAssetReader.

Comment: Ah, I wish I could have been more help :( If I come across anything in the future I will keep you in mind.

Comment: @BloodAxe I came across this, let me know if it helps at all. Seems useful  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html

Comment: thanks for your tries, but i'm looking for reading frames from video file, not the camera device. It's easy to access the camera. 
At this moment i implemented frames capture from video file using AVAssetReader class. However it's not intended for real-time use. It can't provide smooth fps for video in 1280x720. So i'm looking for faster way to access video files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AVPlayer+ AVPlayerItem, it provide you a chance to apply a filter on the display image.